# Check if all characters in a string are 1, 0, or " "

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a boolean function that returns false if the string consists of only 1's, 0's, and spaces.  Otherwise it returns true to the while loop the function call is nested in.  This is the code I have so far:

```
bool check_bin_num(string& bin) {
     for (int i = 0; i <= back.length(); i++) {
          if (!(bin[i] == '0' || bin[i] == '1' || bin[i] == ' ')) {
               return true;
          }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The 1 in your for bracket certainly needs to be an i

Comment: And `i <= back.length()` is wrong unless you want a guaranteed failure on a  null char terminator matching any of those conditions.

Comment: you could also use the `find_first_of` method of `std::string`

Comment: Also your for loop will be executed one too many times, try and spot why

Comment: What's wrong? And I think you meant "bin.length()" instead of "back.length()"

Comment: You sure this wasn't a 'spot the error' homework?

Answer (score 7):

This can be written in one line using [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of):

```
s.find_first_not_of("01 ") == std::string::npos
```

will evaluate to `true` if and only if the `std::string` `s` consists entirely of the characters `'0'`, `'1'` and `' '` (space).

Comment: If you write it using `std::all_of`, then it will work for any sequence, not just strings.